# Error after patches SUPEE-7405 and SUPEE-9767

Tags: magento-1.9, error, supee-7405, supee-9767

I installed pathes `SUPEE-7405` and `SUPEE-9767` and when clicked on `remove` button then cant remove product on magento 1.9 and get below message:

> Cannot remove the item

Please help me.

Comment: Can you please check logs `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log` for error messages and post results?

Comment: i have check logs but there is no error messge

Comment: I found this thread, which mentions a similar issue: https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/SUPEE-7405-Cannot-remove-the-item-from-Cart/td-p/27126.  Are you using an ajax cart extension?  If so, you will need to add `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml("formkey") ?>` to the template which contains the form that is used.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  If it was the solution I mentioned, please accept answer.  If it was something else, add your own answer so others can see what solved the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ajax cart extension, you will need to add

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml("formkey") ?>
```

to the extension's template(s) which contain forms which update the quote.